# Parse CSV in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to automatically parse a CSV document into separate cells in Google Spreadsheets. I'm using the script below, however, it just presents the `,` separated value, whereas, I need those values appear in individual cells. Any ideas?

```
function importCSVFromWeb() {
  var csvUrl = "https://ctrlq.org/data.csv";
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider editing your question. Avoid unnecessary bolding your text and post your code here instead of a link to an image. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: add code as text, not as image

Comment: @barbsan thanks for the tip. Done. Would you know how the problem I described can be solved?

Comment: Have you tried passing [delimiter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv-delimiter)? Like `Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent, ",");`

Comment: @RenatIshmukhamedov I've run your code and it works perfectly. The problem is probably in your csv file, and you need to share it, or a sample of it, so we can understand the layout and any issues. I'm assuming that you are NOT using the `csvUrl` above, because it doesn't exist.